# Updating repository pattern model by sending ViewModel to controller - How to send back to context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, repository-pattern, dbcontext

I have an **Admin** section with a **/Admin/NewCourse** page that I want to use to save details of the newly added course details through a form. The course Model was created using POCO first using Repository pattern.

In my view I have the following:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("NewCourse","Admin",FormMethod.Post))
      {
        <div class="row">
          <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="six columns">
                @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Course.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Course.Name)
              </div>
              <div class="six columns">
                @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Course.Author)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Course.Author)
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                  @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Course.UploadDate)
                  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Course.UploadDate)
                </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                  @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Course.ExpiryDate)
                  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Course.ExpiryDate)
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                  @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Course.Description)
                  @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Course.Description)
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                  @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Course.ParticipationPoints)
                  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Course.ParticipationPoints)
                </div>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit button"/>
        </div>

        }
```

In my controller I have setup a HTTP post in the following manner:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewCourse(AdminViewModel model)
    {
        Course newCourse = new Course();
        newCourse.Name = model.Course.Name;
        newCourse.Author = model.Course.Author;
        newCourse.UploadDate = model.Course.UploadDate;
        newCourse.ExpiryDate = model.Course.ExpiryDate;
        newCourse.Description = model.Course.Description;
        newCourse.ParticipationPoints = model.Course.ParticipationPoints;             
        return View(model);
    }
```

As you can see from the POST above I am passing an AdminViewModel which contains the following lines of code:

```
 private Repository<Course> courseRepository;
```

How can I update my POST method in the controller to save the changes of the new course to the courseRepository list?

Comment: try to return View(newCourse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the implementation of your repository and whether you have a save method implemented or not.

in my implementation of repository pattern, I did it through t4 scaffolding. and it has the following two methods to take care of inserts or updates.

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(TEntity entity)
    {
        dynamic ent = entity;

        if (ent.Id == default(System.Guid)) {
            // New entity
            ent.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(ent);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            _context.Entry(ent).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

so, I first call the insert or update method by passing the newly created entity.
then call the save method which will do the saving of the changes in that context.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Amila

Comment: I have the following two methods in my repository class.

public void Add(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("entity");

            _dbset.Add(entity);
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

My problem is that I am not sure how to call them from the controller. As when I do I am getting a No parameterless method defined for this object

Comment: please define the two functions as I have given above first. Then in your controller post action where you want to save the changed data, after you making changes to your entity, pass that entity to InsertOrUpdate function. it doesn't matter if you instantiate the repository as a global variable or a local variable. after calling the InsertOrUpdate function, call Save function. this will save your data to the database.

Answer (score 1):

you can read my code, i use repository pattern to..

this my controller

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult EditUser(int UserID)
        {
            List<UserViewModel> UserViewModel = _AccountService.userViewModel(UserID);
            return View(UserViewModel.FirstOrDefault());
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditUser(UserViewModel updateUser)
        {
            var UpdateData = _AccountService.UpdateDataUser(updateUser.UserID, updateUser.FullName, updateUser.Email, updateUser.IsActive, updateUser.IsMaster);

            if (UpdateData != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Users");
            }
            return View(UpdateData);
        }
```

this my service class\

```
public List<UserViewModel> userViewModel(int UserID)
        {
            List<User> user = (from d in _UserRepository.All()
                               where d.UserID == UserID
                               select d).ToList();

            List<UserViewModel> userViewModel = new List<UserViewModel>();
            foreach(User users in user)
            {
                userViewModel.Add(new UserViewModel 
                {
                    Email = users.Email,
                    FullName = users.FullName,
                    UserName = users.UserName,
                    UserPassword = users.UserPassword,
                    UserID = users.UserID,
                    HotelID = users.HotelID,
                    IsActive = users.IsActiveq,
                    IsMaster = users.IsMaster
                });
            }
            return userViewModel;
        }



public User UpdateDataUser(int UserID,string FullName, string Email, bool Active, bool MasterUser)
        {
            User user = (from d in _UserRepository.All()
                         where d.UserID == UserID
                         select d).Single();

            var updateData = new UserViewModel 
            {
                UserID = UserID,
                FullName = FullName,
                Email = Email,
                IsActive = Active,
                IsMaster = MasterUser
            };

            user.UserID = updateData.UserID;
            user.FullName = updateData.FullName;
            user.Email = updateData.Email;
            user.IsActiveq = updateData.IsActive;
            user.IsMaster = updateData.IsMaster;

            _UserRepository.Attach(user);
            _UserRepository.CommitChanges();

            return user;
        }
```

Comment: I am getting error: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: did you add your data to database and savechange??

Comment: yes it is giving me a paramerteless constructor error. The only way I was able to get to dbcontext was to declare it again in the controller and this does not seem right to me but even with this the changes are not saving

Comment: you can see my code using repository pattern. i hope can help you

Comment: It is a ViewModel that I am using as the parameter for the POST method not the Model. I need this to then save back to the model repository. I think your example is simply using the model. I am not sure how to relate this to my issue